# Netsuite: Proper Method of Javascript Injection

Tags: javascript, session, netsuite, inject

I'm currently injecting custom Javascript onto specific record types via the User Event Scripts -> Before Load Function script.

In this script, I'm adding a field to the form with type 'inlinehtml', and then adding javascript within  tags.

Is this the Netsuite preferred method? Seems extremely hacky.

Here's the example I'm working with:
Have the built-in Customer form run a check on session vars and, if a specific var is set, to update the page with info based on that var.

I'm injecting js into the page because I need the URL to load to apply a new URL param or change an existing URL param based on the session var.

Answer (score 2):

Your before load event function signature looks like:
`function beforeLoad(type, form, request)`
You can create a client side script and then use it's script id like:

```
function beforeLoad(type, form, request){
  form.setScript('myscriptid');...
```

and Netsuite will load that script and any dependencies (library files) defined in the script definition.